# Facebook Graph API problem

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I've got some trouble with Facebook authentication. Even when I'm logged, the function `getUser()` returns 0

Here's my code :

```
$fb_params = array(
'appId'     => APP_ID,
'secret'    => SECRET_ID
);  
$fb = new Facebook($fb_params);

echo $fb->getUser(); // UID
```

Someone's got an idea?

PS : 'I can no long access to `$fb->api('/me')`, it says it requires an `access_token`, I think it's linked to the authentication issue...'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently not authenticating as a user, only as an application. As a result, the Facebook API can't show you the /me page or respond to a getUser() call since it doesn't know what user you are trying to access the API on behalf of (ie. "Who is /me?"). You will also only be able to access publically-accessible information.

You need to get a user to authenticate your application through Oauth2, store the access_token you are returned, and then include it in any future calls (eg. WIRQjCey1.3600.1309525200.0-509450630|eD6SAR">https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=2227470867|2.AQB-_*WIRQjCey1*.3600.1309525200.0-509450630|eD6SAR...).

To do this using the PHP SDK you can do

```
$loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl();
echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login with Facebook</a>";
```

Clicking that link and having the user authenticate will store the access_token to the $_SESSION, and when you hit refresh the "new Facebook( $fb_params );" constructor will pick out the access token from the $_SESSION and use it for all future calls, so then calls like $fb->getUser(); will return correctly.

There's a functioning example in the examples folder of the SDK, here:
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.
You can use it to try calls while authenticated as an application (public data access only), and then as a user.